# How to setup custom api for Magento with SOAP V2?

Tags: c#, php, web-services, magento, soap

I am on Magento 1.4.1.1 and I am trying to setup a custom function in the API using SOAP v2. I have it working for SOAP v1 but I need v2 so that C# can use it. For v2 the function shows up in the WSDL but alwasy returns this error: Procedure 'testFoo' not present.

Here are my files:

**/app/etc/modules/ABT_Test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <ABT_Test>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </ABT_Test>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**/app/code/local/ABT/Test/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <ABT_Test>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </ABT_Test>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <test>
                <class>ABT_Test_Model</class>
            </test>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**/app/code/local/ABT/Test/etc/api.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api>
        <resources>
            <test>
                <model>test/api</model>
                <title>ABT Test Api</title>
                <methods>
                    <foo translate="title" module="test">
                        <title>Foo Test</title>
                        <method>foo</method>
                        <acl>test/foo</acl>
                    </foo>
                </methods>
            </test>
        </resources>
        <v2>
            <resources_function_prefix>
                <test>test</test>
            </resources_function_prefix>
        </v2>
    </api>
</config>
```

**/app/code/local/ABT/Test/etc/wsdl.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </schema>
    </types>
    <message name="testFooRequest">
        <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
    </message>
    <message name="testFooResponse">
        <part name="result" type="typens:boolean" />
    </message>
    <portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <operation name="testFoo">
            <documentation>Test Foo</documentation>
            <input message="typens:testFooRequest" />
            <output message="typens:testFooResponse" />
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <operation name="testFoo">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
            <input>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
</definitions>
```

**/app/code/local/ABT/Test/Model/API.php**

```
<?php
class ABT_Test_Model_Api extends Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract
{

    public function foo()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

**/app/code/local/ABT/Test/Model/API/V2.php**

```
<?php
class ABT_Test_Model_Api_V2 extends ABT_Test_Model_Api
{
}
?>
```

And here is the code I use to test the API:

```
<?php
    $mageUser   = '########';
    $mageApiKey = '########';

    //SOAP V1
    echo "SOAP V1 <br />";
    $mageUrl    = 'http://www.########.com/api/soap/?wsdl';
    $soap = new SoapClient($mageUrl, array('cache_wsdl' => 0));

    try {
        $sessionID = $soap->login($mageUser, $mageApiKey);
        var_dump($soap->call($sessionID, 'test.foo', array()));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Exception: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br />';
    }

    //SOAP V2
    echo "SOAP V2 <br />";
    $mageUrl2    = 'http://www.########.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl';
    $soap2 = new SoapClient($mageUrl2, array('cache_wsdl' => 0));

    try {
        $sessionID2 = $soap2->login($mageUser, $mageApiKey);
        var_dump($soap2->testFoo($sessionID2));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Exception: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br />';
    }
?>
```

I obscured the username, password and url. The function shows up in the v2 WSDL and the php code recognizes that it is in the WSDL but I still get the error: Procedure 'testFoo' not present.

So what am I missing?

EDIT:
I did what Zyava suggested and it got my example working. I then copied the folder and did an exact (case sensitive) find and replace to use a meaningful Module name and function name. I was careful to pick names that I didn't think would be reserve words. On the new module the call on the v1 WSDL works fine but the v2 gives the same "Procedure 'xxx' not present" message. I then went and renamed the method on the test from 'Foo' to 'Fooz' and I got this message: "Resource path is not callable." I find it interesting that I get a different message. This leads me to believe there is some cache/configuration/something that is causing the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I should warn you that Magento doesn't support SOAP v2 format for now, api/v2_soap/?wsdl is just [second version of soap api](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/introduction#soap).

1.

```
<models>
    <test>
        <class>ABT_Test_Model</class>
    </test>
</models>
```

Because you are writing module which isn't core, you should write `<abt_test>`

2.`<model>test/api</model>`. Should be `<model>abt_test/api</model>` in your case.

3.`<acl>test/foo</acl>`.

Does this acl section exist in your adminhtml.xml?

Comment: Sorry, What you suggested did work but I had cache issues. The issue was the PHP WSDL cache on the server. I had to add this:

`ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '0');`

Comment: @Zyava I don't get it, why should use <model>abt_test/api</model> instead of <model>test/api</model> ? As 'test' has been defined as ABT_Test_Model. Why is it still need to include the package name?

Comment: There is a best practice for non-core modules to use full module name (with package name) everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

bygrace,

your code is so perfect!

add

> ```
> ....
>   <resources_alias>
>       <test>test</test>
>   </resources_alias>
> .....
> ```

same level with

```
<resources> and <v2>
```

on Api.xml

and it'll be working good.

Answer (score 0):

I has having the same issue and i tried clearing the tmp file as i had hosted it using xampp it didnt work i was getting `Procedure ххх not present exception`, I had to **disable the cache management in the admin page of the server**.
**How to disable Cache in Admin page**
In the admin page under the system there is a section called cache management disable everything during the development phase or else any change you do wont be reflected in the wsdl.