# Magento Custom method API V2 is not a valid method for this service

Tags: api, magento, soap, wsdl

I created a custom method to the Magento SOAP API and it worked well so far. Now I want to create the same method to the Magento SOAP API V2.

I created the WSDL.xml and the V2.php Class files (below), and when I try call my method in V2 API, I got this error:

`Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("pacoteCreatelink") is not a valid method for this service in [...]`

Although the error be clear, it seems to me that my new method in soap v2 is not being recognized. I must pass something. Any Ideas?

**Files:**

```
Company
    Bundleapi
        etc
            config.xml
            api.xml
            wsdl.xml
        Model
            Pacote
                Api
                    V2.php
                Api.php
```

**V2.php:**

```
<?php
class Company_Bundleapi_Model_Pacote_Api_V2 extends Company_Bundleapi_Model_Pacote_Api
{
    public function createlink($message)
    {
        return $message;
    }
}
```

**api.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api>
        <resources>
            <bundle_link translate="title" module="company_bundleapi">
                <title>Create Bundle link</title>
                <model>bundleapi/pacote_api</model>
                <methods>
                    <createlink translate="title" module="company_bundleapi">
                        <title>Create link Options Bundle</title>
                    </createlink>
                    <cleanlink translate="title" module="company_bundleapi">
                        <title>Clean link beetwen Bundle and Simple Products</title>
                    </cleanlink>
                </methods>
            </bundle_link>
        </resources>
    </api>
</config>
```

**wsdl.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
         xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
         xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
         name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
<types>
</types>
<message name="pacoteCreatelinkRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="message" type="xsd:string" />
</message>
<message name="pacoteCreatelinkResponse">
    <part name="result" type="xsd:string" />
</message>
<portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
    <operation name="pacoteCreatelink">
        <documentation>Create Link to Bundle Products</documentation>
        <input message="typens:pacoteCreatelinkRequest" />
        <output message="typens:pacoteCreatelinkResponse" />
    </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <operation name="pacoteCreatelink">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
        <input>
            <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
    <port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
        <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
    </port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

**config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Bundleapi>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_Bundleapi>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <bundleapi>
                <class>Company_Bundleapi_Model</class>
            </bundleapi>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860917/extending-magentos-api-soap-v2-is-not-a-valid-method-for-this-service), [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9499/how-can-i-create-a-custom-soap-xml-rpc-v1-v2-api-in-magento) and [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25914/magento-api-v2-methods-not-present) before.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a "v2" section to your api.xml, like so:

```
   <config>
      <api>
         <resources>
            ...
         </resources>
         <v2>
            <resources_function_prefix>
               <bundle_link>pacote</bundle_link>
            </resources_function_prefix>
         </v2>
      </api>
   </config>
```

This tells the Magento API adapter that calls starting with "pacote" are referring to methods in the resource "bundle_link" (which you've defined in the `<resources>` section of api.xml already).

Comment: Oh one other thing: check that your API client isn't caching the WSDL. I spent days tearing my hair out over the "not a valid method for this resource" error, to eventually find that my module was fine, it was just PHP caching. GRRR. The SoapClient constructor accepts an options array, make sure this has cache_wsdl set to WSDL_CACHE_NONE during development.