# Magento custom soap API not working

Tags: php, magento, soap

I am trying to create custom soap API in  magento , [I used this codes for my cutom API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519556/how-to-setup-custom-api-for-magento-with-soap-v2)
It works fine on my PC but on the server it is not working. when I log exception from **app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php** I Got this

> 2013-03-20T15:09:16+00:00 DEBUG (7):
> include(Mage/Abt/Test/Model/Api.php): failed to open stream: No such
> file or directory/opt/lampp/htdocs/mag/lib/Varien/Autoload.php
>
>  2013-03-20T15:09:16+00:00 DEBUG (7): include(): Failed
> opening 'Mage/Abt/Test/Model/Api.php' for inclusion
> (include_path='/opt/lampp/htdocs/mag/app/code/local:/opt/lampp/htdocs/mag/app/code/community:/opt/lampp/htdocs/mag/app/code/core:/opt/lampp/htdocs/mag/lib:.:/opt/lampp/lib/php')/opt/lampp/htdocs/mag/lib/Varien/Autoload.php

I checked the file **/opt/lampp/htdocs/mag/lib/Varien/Autoload.php** its exist , but why it is showing `failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

any idea about this problem?.

Comment: Check once is your compilation is enabled or disabled in your admin panel.System=>tools=>compliation if enabled then run compliation and diable it...

Comment: If your local environment is on Windows, you should check the letter cases of your folders and files; Windows is case-insensitive