# Accessing configurable product attributes via Magento SOAP v2

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How do I access the list of configurable attributes for a configurable product I request via SOAP v2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this default Magento SOAP API. You should extend the API.

[Creating a Custom API or Extending the Core API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html)
[How to setup custom api for Magento with SOAP V2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519556/how-to-setup-custom-api-for-magento-with-soap-v2)

Comment: How is it that the Magento native mobile app can do this? Can I use that same API by any chance?

Comment: @Dayson I am not sure where this function available. If that so, you can create same function in normal store.

Comment: Is this still not possible?

Comment: @KevinWu In Magento 2 should be possible because they had changed many things, specifically API's.